# Adding a constraint programmatically to a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

UPDATE: This appears to not have anything to do with auto layout. Even if I disable auto-layout I still get the same :(

I am adding a series of `UIImageView`s to a scroll view and after spending hours trying to diagnose the 
issue, I have come to the conclusion that it has to be a constraint issue that is pushing my `UIImage`s down. Please see the attached image:

[image]

As you can see the `UIImage`s are pushed down as I have marked the `UIScrollView` background red. I have also attached a picture of the constraints for my `UIScrollView`:

[image]

Here are the properties of my scrollview:

[image]

How do I get about setting a constraint on the `UIImageView` so that it centers in the `UIScrollView` horizontally?  I am using the following code to populate the `UIScrollView` with the images.

```
for (UIView *v in self.scrollview.subviews)
    {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGRect workingFrame = self.scrollview.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

    for(NSDictionary *dict in info)
    {

        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

        MyManager * myManager = [MyManager sharedInstance];
        [myManager.assets addObject:imageview];
        [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        imageview.frame = workingFrame;
        [self.scrollview addSubview:imageview];
        workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
    }

    [self.scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Redcolor is the textview?

Comment: There is a textview right behind the uiscrollview and that shows up when one clicks on "text" from the uisegment buttons at the top.

Comment: red color is the scrollview

Answer (score 0):

workingFrame.origin.y = 0;  fixed it